# Application object in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, applicationcontext

I used to write web development application using Servlets and jsps, recently i have started learning spring.
Using Servlets i had built an application in which i have maintained the two objects using application context and some objects using session. Now in springs i don't know how to do this.

Lets understand the problem with an example.

I have following obj

```
player p1= new Player();
player p2 = new Player();

match m1 = new Match(p1,p2);
```

I want to maintain the match obj in application context so that i can manage the data using session of both the users/players and reflect on both side.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068478/spring-mvc-3-0-application-session-scope

Answer (score 0):

In Spring terms `application` is a `singleton` scope. Please, read more info about Spring MVC around the Internet.

**UPDATE**

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-web
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm

And here you can find a lot of 'Hello worlds' for many Spring cases: https://spring.io/guides

Comment: then please share some good links which will focus on only this area.....as i can't go in details right now

Comment: Updated answer with links on the matter

Comment: How does this answer the question? Essentially this is a link only answer.

Comment: @Bart, general question - general answer. Since Eager Developer is newbie in Spring, there is need to follow him to right way via some good tutorials. I don't see reason to explain entire Spring in the answer on SO. Although I made an answer to the question re. 'Application object'

Comment: I get your point. Still the question was not to explain Spring in general but how to manage the `Match` object in the application context. Also, *"good tutorials"* is very subjective and I'm sure Eager Developer has what it takes to use Google and search for information himself.

Comment: yep....the tutorials gonna take time..i want an instant fix for the above issue with a brief description .

Comment: Since your question is very common and it isn't clear what you already have or know, it's difficult to provide for you a short answer not to hurt you. That's why I suggest to start from docs to fix gaps in knowledge and after that a lot of question might disappear

Comment: Thanks....i would have appreciated if you have answered it , instead of writing a comment again. But anyways....i think u r right ... i should go with tutorial first tutorials :)